# Однородные члены или ССП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, ссп, сложное-предложение

*Возможно, ему приходится 3–4 дня быть недоступным для окружающего мира, зато он погружён в работу полностью и его продуктивность на максимуме. **Так он выполняет работу быстрее[,] и затем со спокойной душой предаётся безделью.***

Я бы счёл "выполняет" и "предаётся" однородными членами, если бы не было обстоятельства, выраженного местоимённым наречием "так", которое очевидно не относится ко второму предикату ("так предаётся безделью" не имеет смысла).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю "так" нужно отнести ко всей ситуации в целом:

**Так (в результате) он выполняет работу быстрее и затем со спокойной душой предаётся безделью.**

Comment: К сожалению, такого значения для слова «так» в словаре не зафиксировано — только «указанным способом, образом действия».

Comment: Я ошибся. Значение, близкое к вашему, есть на Грамоте: _2. Союз. То же, что «в таком случае, следовательно»... "Ну, у кого спросить? У Самуильсона? Так Самуильсон скажет, что он вас в глаза не видал" (Н. Тэффи, Свой человек)_. Однако, как видите, в этом значении "так" произносится без ударения.

Answer (score 1):

**Так он выполняет работу / быстрЕе // и затем со спокойной душой / предаётся бездЕлью.**

(Показано актуальное членение предложения и фразовые ударения. В первой части местоимение ***так*** вынесено в начало предложения для его логического выделения).

**Обычные однородные члены**, имеющие зависимые слова.

Вопрос об изменении статуса предложения при наличии однородных сказуемых ставится в особых случаях ― **при большой коммуникативной расчлененности и самостоятельности частей предложения.**

Здесь же простое перечисление действий.

Comment: В таком случае обстоятельство «так» в препозиции относится к обоим однородным членам, хотя по смыслу это не так.

Comment: А почему "так" относится к обоим членам? Одной препозиции для этого недостаточно, всё как раз определяется по смыслу.

Comment: Я бы согласился с вами, если бы «так» находилось после подлежащего «он» и перед первым сказуемым «выполняет», но «так» находится перед подлежащим и, таким образом, относится ко всей фразе.

Comment: Откуда всё это, что за правило?  Порядок слов внутри фразы строится с учетом правильной  расстановки логических ударений  и удобства произношения. А общий член вообще может быть и в середине предложения, например: "Губы Кати не улыбались и глаза выражали недоумение".

Comment: Я привёл это в качестве своей субъективной точки зрения, исходя из того, как мне слышится эта фраза: что "так" относится к обоим сказуемым. Если по правилам синтаксиса обстоятельство может быть вынесено в начало предложение и при этом относится только к первому сказуемому, я готов согласится.

Comment: Синтаксис определяет грамматические связи между словами в предложении, но в реальном предложении происходит перестройка  порядка слов, связанная с расстановкой логических (тонических) ударений (это тема актуального членения предложения). Что касается  Вашего "слышится", то Вы слышите паузу перед "затем", обозначающую перелом интонации? Предложение фонетически делится на две части, причем в начале каждой находится местоименное наречие

Comment: Спасибо, изучил этот вопрос. Я так понимаю, знак "/" обозначает разграничение между темой и ремой? И кстати, на реме всегда делается ударение?

Comment: 1) Тема и рема  (предмет и сообщение о предмете) - это структура простого неосложненного предложения. Оно состоит из двух фраз,  разделанных паузой (//), обозначающей перелом интонации. Каждая фраза имеет тоническое ударение (движение голоса вверх или вниз). Если фраза достаточно распространена, то приходится делить ее на дополнительные смысловые отрезки (синтагмы), разделенные произносительными паузами (/), поэтому не каждый отрезок имеет тоническое ударение.

Comment: 2) Если в предложении появляются однородные члены, то каждый их них имеет фразовое ударение, то есть система ударений перестраивается.  Но если два однородных члена связаны одиночным союзом, то интонационная структура строится по образцу простого предложения с двумя фразами, но внутреннее деление фразы (/) может присутствовать. 3)  Обычно фразовое ударение приходится на конец фразы, но его можно сместить на любое другое слово. В этом случае оно приобретает логическое ударение.

Comment: К слову о том, что позиции обстоятельства в начале предложения недостаточно, чтобы отнести его к обоим однородным членам: тогда предложение "На консультации мы обсудим все детали и приступим к работе" составлено верно, т. к. очевидно, что "приступим к работе" мы не во время консультации?

Comment: "На консультации мы обсудим все детали и (потом)  приступим к работе".  Смысл неясен: они прямо на консультации приступят к работе?

Comment: Как я уже написал, очевидно, что не на консультации. Получается, обязательно наличие обстоятельства перед вторым сказуемым, чтобы недопустить его синтаксическую связь с обстоятельством в начале предложения?

Comment: Да,  наличие второго обстоятельства необходимо.